# How to use Guild.kick()?

Tags: java, discord-jda

I'm trying to implement a kick command for my bot, but `Guild.kick(Member member)` doesn't actually kick the specified user. IntelliJ simply says "Result of `Guild.kick(Member member)` is ignored". Here's my implementation (with non-relevant code removed):

```
public void onGuildMessageReceived(@Nonnull GuildMessageReceivedEvent e) {
    // other code

    g = e.getGuild();

    // other code

    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("kick")) {
        
        // other code

        String target = getConnectedName(args, 1, 0); // gets name of target from message
        List<Member> nameList = g.getMembersByEffectiveName(target, true);
        try {
            target = nameList.get(0).getAsMention();
            c.sendMessage("Target: "+target).queue();
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            c.sendMessage("No user found with the name \"target\" in this guild.").queue();
        }
        Member targetM = null;
        if (!nameList.isEmpty()) {
            targetM = nameList.get(0);
            c.sendMessage(targetM.toString()).queue();
    
            try {
                g.kick(targetM);
            } catch (HierarchyException e) {
                error403MissingPermission(); // sends a message that user is missing permission to use !kick
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why this won't work / what's wrong with my implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19)-Troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-using-x

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
`Guild.kick(Member member)` has to be queued like `TextChannel.sendMessage(String text)` , so the correct usage is `g.kick(Member member).queue();`. Credit to @Minn